# How do I rearrange elements in a 1D matrix array in-place?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, rust

I want to align the memory of a 5x5 matrix represented as an one-dimensional array.

The original array looks like this:

```
let mut a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25];
```

or

```
    [ 1  2  3  4  5  ]
    [ 6  7  8  9  10 ]
a = [ 11 12 13 14 15 ]
    [ 16 17 18 19 20 ]
    [ 21 22 23 24 25 ]
```

with a length of 25 elements.

after resizing the memory to memory aligned bounds (power of 2), the array will look like this:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
```

or

```
    [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  ]
    [ 9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ]
    [ 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 ]
    [ 25 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ]
a = [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ]
    [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ]
    [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ]
    [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ]
```

the len of a is now 64 elements.

so it will become an 8x8 matrix

the goal is to have following representation:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 6 7 8 9 10 0 0 0 11 12 13 14 15 0 0 0 16 17 18 19 20 0 0 0 21 22 23 24 25 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
```

or

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  0 0 0 ]
[ 6  7  8  9  10 0 0 0 ]
[ 11 12 13 14 15 0 0 0 ]
[ 16 17 18 19 20 0 0 0 ]
[ 21 22 23 24 25 0 0 0 ]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0 0 0 ]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0 0 0 ]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0 0 0 ]
```

The background is to have `a` memory aligned to a power of two, so calculations can be partially done in parallel ( for OpenCL `float4`, or the available vector sizes.). I also do not want to use a new array to simply insert the old elements at the correct positions to keep memory consumption low.

At first, I thought about swapping the elements at the range, where there should be a zero with the elements at the end of the array, keeping a pointer to the elements and simulating a queue, but elements would stack up towards the end, and I didn't came up with a working solution.

My language of choice is rust. Is there any smart algorithm to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I also know that a 2D array will represented as a 1D array with contingous elements in memory as well. But I couldn't see an improvement of a possible algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not prematurely optimizing? "Resizing" memory usually involves making a copy already, so you might as well allocate the new memory and then copy the elements into place as you see fit.

Comment: Definitely something I thought about as well, so thanks for pointing that out. I am using Vec, which is heap allocated and keeps a capacity, that "might" be larger than the actual length. But I cannot rely on that. Maybe a solution would be to preallocate the "correct" size, and fill the elements accordingly. Anyways, I am also interested in a solution to the problem above as well ;) I will keep trying, updating / providing a solution, if I succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an N * N matrix represented as a vector of size N^2, then you resize the vector to M^2 (M > N), so that the first N^2 elements are the original ones. Now you want to rearrange the original elements, so that the N * N sub-matrix in the upper left of the M * M matrix is the same as the original.

- One thing to note is that if you go backwards you will never overwrite a value that you will need later.
- The position of index X in the M * M matrix is row X / M (integer division) and column X % M.
- The desired position of index X is row X / N and column X % N
- An element at row R and column C in the M * M matrix has the index R * M + C

Now taking all this information we can come up with the formula to get the new index Y for the old index X:

```
Y = (X / N) * M + (X % N)
```

So you can just make a loop from N^2 - 1 to N and copy the element to the new position calculated with the formula and set its original position to 0. (Everything is 0-based, I hope rust is 0-based as well or you will have to add some +1.)

Answer (score 1):

According to [maraca's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60904798/8725011) solution, the code would look like this:

```
fn zeropad<T: Copy>(
    first: T,
    data: &mut Vec<T>,
    dims: (usize, usize),
) -> (usize, usize) {
    let r = next_pow2(dims.0);
    let c = next_pow2(dims.1);

    if (r, c) == (dims.0, dims.1) {
        return (r, c);
    }

    let new_len = r * c;
    let old_len = data.len();
    let old_col = dims.1;

    // resize
    data.resize(new_len, first);

    for i in (old_col..old_len).rev() {
        let row: usize = i / c;
        let col: usize = i % c;

        // bigger matrix
        let pos_old = row * c + col;

        // smaller matrix
        let pos_new = (i / dims.1) * c + (i % dims.1);

        data[pos_new] = data[pos_old];
        data[pos_old] = first;
    }
    return (r, c);
}
```